# Appropriate visualization for this kind of data

Tags: time-series, visualization

**Late edit:** currently working through the FlameGraphs bibliography [here](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html). It looks like what I'm doing is similar to an icicle chart, but with passage of time on the x-axis. The author mentions inspirations for this FlameGraph that have this specific trait (time on x-axis), but I'll need to follow through to see if anyone implemented exactly the same thing.

I'm looking to visualize the flow of nested sub-tasks in my web service. The resulting visualization is probably going to look like a hybrid of a treemap, a dendrogram and a Gantt chart, and I've a feeling that there is a standard chart for it that I'm struggling to find.

### Data

Each time a request is served, I log an object that contains a multi-level N-tree of everything the service did to serve the request, and how long it took.

For example, I log a start and end (relative to the request timeline) of the *database call*, as well as how long it took to *connect*, *execute a query*, and *process the result into a model*. The latter three operations are treated as sub-tasks for the *database call*.

This is what a simplified execution log would look like the listing below. Note that I have hundreds of operations, and some of them are 5-10 levels deep.

```json
{
    "name": "total", // scope name
    "s": 100,        // start
    "e": 700,        // end
    "c": [           // scopes nested under this one
        {
            "name": "database",
            "s": 200,
            "e": 500,
            "c": [
                {
                    "name": "connect",
                    "s": 200,
                    "e": 300
                },
                {
                    "name": "query",
                    "s": 300,
                    "e": 500,
                    "c":[
                    {
                        "name": "subquery",
                        "s": 400,
                        "e": 470,
                    }]
                }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "ui",
            "s": 510,
            "e": 700,
            "c":[{
                "name": "render",
                "s": 520,
                "e": 690
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

### Current approach

I've written a small Haskell program to parse the tree and output the following chart onto an HTML Canvas:
[image: current visualization]

At the moment, I can nicely represent the nested nature of the sub-tasks, and see where the tasks are relative to each other on the timeline.

I don't really want to build a chart renderer from scratch though.

### Difference from chart types I've considered

**Nested bar chart:** bar charts usually have the bars starting at the 0, and all stacking usually happens based on bar size. I need more of a timeline view.

**Gantt chart:** very similar idea-wise, but usually tracks 'jobs' or 'projects' as rows, and normally doesn't deal with nested jobs.

**Treemap:** in treemap, all values get assigned the *area* based on their scalar value. Here, my area is made up of rows (number of sub-tasks) and width (task duration in milliseconds)

**Dendrogram:** close in terms of data structure, but I can't think of a way to render it in a way that helps to show the start/end/duration of nested tasks well.

**Flame Chart/Flame Graph (late addition, see edit at the top):** at last I've found someone with similar ideas! Looks like people working with performance profiler software have been working to visualize nested call stacks - in a very similar fashion, but sizing things by call count vs. duration.

### The question

Am I reinventing the wheel?

I feel that there should exist a standard visualization type (probably well supported by common tools as well) that can render the chart above just as well.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be a flamegraph with time on the x-axis and nested hierarchy of functions on the y-axis. The width of each box on the graph represents the amount of time that function took to execute as a percentage of the total time of its parent function.

Something like this:
[image]